# New UL added to DOM but not converted to Sortable UL jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

The first UL that is directly on the page works great, and is sort able.
When I try to add another UL either with JS or AJAX, its just a UL and not sort able. Is there a way to convert a HTML UL to a jquery sort able?

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
} );

$( function() {
$( "#sortable2" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable2" ).disableSelection();
} );


function myFunctionNew() {
var node = document.createElement("LI");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("sortable").appendChild(node);
}

function myFunction(img_src) {
document.getElementById("sortable").innerHTML += "<li class=ui-state-default><span class=ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s></span><img src="+img_src+".jpg></li>";
}


function myFunctionNewNEW()
{
document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML ="<ul id=sortable2><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul>";
}
</script>


</head>

<body>

<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<br/><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=myFunction('person')>Person</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=myFunction('person2')>Person2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=myFunctionNew()>Add ME</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=myFunctionNewNEW()>NEW Add ME</a>

<div id=testing>test area</div>

</body>

</html>
```

the added items that are added to the html page should be sortable UL jquery

Comment: Thank you very much, i was reading about the refesh option but couldnt get it to work right, and it did exactly what i wanted, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sup>As I said</sup> Plugins run with rendered HTML .And can't detect the newly added content until you refresh the plugin or call the plugin again after append the new content .. so with `sortable` and after append the content try to use `$("#sortable2").sortable('refresh');` or call the plugin again `$("#sortable2" ).sortable();`

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});


function myFunctionNew() {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("sortable").appendChild(node);
}

function myFunction(img_src) {
  document.getElementById("sortable").innerHTML += "<li class=ui-state-default><span class=ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s></span><img src="+img_src+".jpg></li>";
}


function myFunctionNewNEW()
{
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML ="<ul id=sortable2><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul>";
  $("#sortable2").sortable();  //<<<<<<<<<< HERE
  $("#sortable2").disableSelection(); //<<<<<<<<<< HERE
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<br/><br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=myFunction('person')>Person</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=myFunction('person2')>Person2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=myFunctionNew()>Add ME</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=myFunctionNewNEW()>NEW Add ME</a>

<div id=testing>test area</div>
```

Same idea with `ajax` you need to call the plugin in ajax success callback function and after new content appended